# Build a learning platform - link exercise to its lesson - onetoone field or foreign key?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm trying to build a small project - an e-learning project. I'm trying to bind some exercises to its lesson id.

I've read the django docs and I don't know if I should use a OneToOne field or a Foreign Key.

I've tried the idea with the foreign key, as I feel like this is the right answer.
lessons - models.py (Lectie = lesson)

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Lectie(models.Model):
    YTLink = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    PDFLink = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
```

exercises - models.py (intrebare = question, variante = options, variantaCorecta = the right answer)

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
from lectii.models import Lectie

# Create your models here.
class Exercises(models.Model):
    idLectie = models.ForeignKey(Lectie, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    intrebare = models.CharField(max_length = 300)
    variante = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=300), null=True)
    variantaCorecta = models.IntegerField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.intrebare
```

I'm getting this error:

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'idLectie' to exercises without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
```

I will only add these questions from the back-end, they will not be added by the user, and I get this answer. Django doesn't know what ID to bind the exercise to.

So how should my model look so I can bind the exercise to its lesson? Is it okay this way and just adding a blank=True, and changing the ID after that? Or should I switch to a one-to-one relationship? Thanks.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a lesson has *multiple* lessons, then a `ForeignKey` is appropriate. A `OneToOne` field is just a `ForeignKey` with a `unique=True` constraint, meaning only one relationship between the two objects is allowed.

As for your error, you have two options:

1) Set a `default=...` attribute, which wouldn't make sense in this case since it doesn't seem there should be a "default" exercise for each lesson.

2) Set the ForeignKey to `blank=True, null=True`, then set each `Lesson` manually. You can always remove `blank=True, null=True` and then migrate again.

Comment: Thanks for replying to both my problems. Now I understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a default value:

```
 DEFAULT_ID = 1
 idLectie = models.ForeignKey(Lectie, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,  default=DEFAULT_ID)
```

Also make sure that there is a row in the table of Other.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I accepted the other answer though because it was more complete.

Comment: @OctavianNiculescu sure i hope you got solution